# In the application my tab bar just show 2 of 3 icon last bar's icon not come. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I create a bottom Tab bar and add 3 tab. After that I added icon all of them but just two of them appear in the screen. I did same thing for every screen but its not working. How can I fix that appearing error ?

````
const Tabs = (createBottomTabNavigator({
  Transaction:{
    screen : Transaction,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel: 'Transaction',
      tabBarIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="exchange" color={'white'} size={25} type='font-awesome' />
      )
    }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="home" color={'white'} size={25} type='font-awesome' />
      )
    }
  },
  Receive: {
    screen: Receive,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Receive',
      tabBarIcon: () => {
        <Icon name='bookmark' color={'white'} size={25} type='font-awesome' />
      }
    }
  }
},
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: '#202349',
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#090a0f',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#090a0f',
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      },
    },
  }));```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Receive tab definition looks slightly different than the others, try it with:

```
Receive: {
    screen: Receive,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Receive',
      tabBarIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="bookmark" color={'white'} size={25} type='font-awesome' />
      )
    }
  }
```

Explanation: In your original code you are not returning the Icon in your tabBarIcon function (for the third icon).

Otherwise (if that doesn't solve your problem), pls provide more information about how you are using it. Ideally in a codepen.